# Universal Linking working even IF I haven't updated the apple-app-site-association file

Tags: ios9

For my app I see that Universal linking is working even when I hadn't set up the apple-app-site-association file enabling universal linking. I am however using the same file for handoff.

I then tried modifying the "apple-app-site-association" file to include the "applinks" dict and by leaving the "paths" field empty, I expected no link to get redirected to the app. Ihe links are still opening in the app inspire of this.

Has anybody else seen this behavior?

A similar question was asked in the apple developer forum but there is no reply from apple. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/28606#28606

How does one set up the file to enable handoff but disable universal linking?

Comment: Whoa, that is wild. Please keep us updated. That would be pretty crazy. Can you post a link to your app / site so that others can experience this?

Comment: I will keep this thread posted when I get an update. For now we have included a ["/none"] for the path parameter.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I want my website to do handoff, but don't want to load my app for every link to my domain.  So far everything that I have tried has failed.

Comment: In the apple-app-site-association file, try making the "paths" field point to "/none" to disable universal linking completely. If you want universal linking to only some parts of your app, then only add that paths to the file in the "paths" field. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have reputation to comment so apologies for putting this as an answer...

Have you solved this? This might not be correct but according to the Apple doco, the apple-app-site-association file is checked ON INSTALL. Wish that was better clarified on their end but hoping an update to the app will get the system to recheck the apple-app-site-association file contents? It would be a real pain if it requires a reinstall of the app for it to update with the any potentially updated JSON. Still working on configuring Universal Links otherwise I'd test myself.

Here's the link to the Shared Web Credentials doco which I've found to have the best information on this apple-app-site-association file, specifically look at the "Validating the Site Association File" section.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/SharedWebCredentialsRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014989